# Trying to write the content of a List<Point> into txt file(WindowsForms C#)

Tags: c#

Should feed the mouse coordinates when clicked in pictureBox1 into List. Then I want to send the contents of List into myFile.txt

I am getting particular error that Point is type and cannot be used as variable. What is the solution?

So here is the code:

```
private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var mouseEventArgs = e as MouseEventArgs;
    Point rp = new Point(mouseEventArgs.X, mouseEventArgs.Y);
    List<Point> pts =  new List<Point>();
    pts.Add(rp);        

    //StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\Users\\Lenny\\Desktop\\new2.txt");
    //writer.WriteLine("X="  + mouseEventArgs.X + "Y=" + mouseEventArgs.Y);
}

public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    File.AppendAllLines("new.txt", Point);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to write coordinates as a text file and not in binary format ?

Comment: @Fabjan I will feed the txt file into another program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Point` is a type and cannot be passed to `File.AppendAllLines` because that expects a `IEnumerable<string>` as the second parameter.  Instead you should pass the list.  But your problem is that the list is local to the `pictureBox1_Click` method.  So you need to make it a class field and then pass it.  Also you have to translate the `Point`s to `string`s.

Finally you should be using the `MouseClick` event instead of the `Click` event in order to get the desired information.

```
private List<Point> pts =  new List<Point>();
private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Point rp = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    pts.Add(rp);    
}

public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    File.AppendAllLines("new.txt", pts.Select(p => p.ToString()));
    // OR
    // File.AppendAllLines("new.txt", pts.Select(p => "X= " + p.X + " Y= " + p.Y));
    pts.Clear();
}
```

I also added a `Clear` after writing the file assuming that at that point you'd want to "start over".

Comment: It is better to use `Control.MouseClick` here instead of `Click`. Also, since there is `as` operator, there must be null-checking after it.

Comment: Thanks it did compile now. However, it is not writing into file. Saying that => {"The given path's format is not supported."} The path i wrote looks like this: File.WriteAllLines("@C:\\Users\\Lenny\\Desktop\\new2.txt", pts.Select(p => p.ToString()));

Comment: @Lenny Why do you have a @ at the beginning of the path?

Comment: @Lenny You might be confusing that with verbatim strings.  If you put the @ before the string then you don't have to escape the backslashes `@"C:\Users\Lenny\Desktop\new2.txt"`

Comment: @juharr Oh, ok I got it. Thanks a lot for the help! Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick.  You can save the points into a member list and then use Linq to put the points into an IEnumerable that can be sent to WriteAllLines.

You might want to use AppendAllLines if you want to continually add points to an existing file.  I have edited the post to remove points from the points list after writing them to the file.  You could do this and continue to add new points to the list and then remove them on append.

One other note, you don't have to format the string for output when you write the lines out the file.  You could simply let the point type convert to string for you.  You could also format this more nicely so that you could more easily parse the file later.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private List<Point> points = new List<Point>(); 
    private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var mouseEventArgs = e as MouseEventArgs;
        Point rp = new Point(mouseEventArgs.X, mouseEventArgs.Y);
        points.Add(rp);

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        File.WriteAllLines("c:\\temp\\new.txt", points.Select(point => "X: " + point.X + "  Y: " + point.Y));
        points.Clear();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather, than using the "Click" event, you should use the "MouseDown" event. IF you're on Visual Studio, go to the designer, click on the picturebox, look at the properties and click on the lightning icon to get to the eventhandlers and then double click on "MouseDown".

Comment: any particular reason?

Comment: The use of MouseEventArgs

Comment: Ok. I will try doing that way too. Thanks!